# Using Windows 10 PowerShell to Bulk Resize All Images in a Directory

Tags: powershell

Can you please let me know if it is possible to bulk resize all images in a folder using Windows 10 PowerShell command

```
$path = "D:/imgs/Nature" #target directory

[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing")
Get-ChildItem -recurse ($path) -include @("*.png", "*.jpg") |
ForEach-Object {
  $image = [System.Drawing.image]::FromFile( $_ )
}
```

Comment: maybe this module could help you https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Resize-Image-A-PowerShell-3d26ef68

Comment: I already tried this but looks like not functioning on Windows 10